# How do I benchmark a function that modifies its input?

Tags: go, benchmarking

When I'm benchmarking a function that modifies its input, I have to copy the test data for each loop of the benchmark, and pause the timer while I'm doing so. This can mean that if I run `go test -bench MyTest -benchtime 1s` the test can take 2 full minutes rather than 1 second.

Am I doing something wrong or will I just have to live with this?

---

More context:

I'm writing a program for reading syslog logs. Part of my logging paradigm is that the first line of a logged message contains readable text, and following lines contain "extra information", like a stack trace. My log reader therefore (among other things) splits the message on the first line break, which is escaped to `#012` by rsyslog.

Here is the code for that:

```
// Splits the main line from extra information
func splitMessageExtra(line *string) string {
    var prev rune

    for i, char := range *line {
        if prev == 0 && char == '#' {
            prev = char
            continue
        }

        if prev == '#' && char == '0' {
            prev = char
            continue
        }

        if prev == '0' && char == '1' {
            prev = char
            continue
        }

        if prev == '1' && char == '2' {
            extra := (*line)[i+1:]
            *line = (*line)[0 : i-3]

            return extra
        }

        prev = 0
    }

    return ""
}
```

It originally used `strings.Split` and returned new strings, but cpu profiling showed that it was way too slow.

Here is the benchmark function:

```
var testMessage = `Feb 10 15:16:20 foo_stats[-] (warning): [foo_stats.postfix, line 166, thread "processor_mta03"]: Skipped line because there is no context:#012Feb 10 15:16:20 mta03 postfix/qmgr[7419]: ABCDEF123: from=<>, size=24431, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

func BenchmarkSplitMessageExtra(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        msg := string([]byte(testMessage))
        b.StartTimer()

        splitMessageExtra(&msg)
    }
}
```

Here's a run without pausing the timer:

```
$ go test -bench SplitMessageExtra -benchtime 1s
BenchmarkSplitMessageExtra-8     3000000           434 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/Hubro/logreader  1.730s
```

And here's a run with the exact benchmark function above:

```
$ go test -bench SplitMessageExtra -benchtime 1s
BenchmarkSplitMessageExtra-8     5000000           385 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/Hubro/logreader  100.563s
```

Notice it takes AGES to run.

Answer (score 1):

Your code and benchmark do seem slow. Here's a faster version.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

// Splits the main line from extra information
func splitMessageExtra(line *string) string {
    const newline = "#012"
    i := strings.Index(*line, newline)
    if i < 0 {
        return ""
    }
    extra := (*line)[i+len(newline):]
    *line = (*line)[0:i]
    return extra
}

var testMessage = `Feb 10 15:16:20 foo_stats[-] (warning): [foo_stats.postfix, line 166, thread "processor_mta03"]: Skipped line because there is no context:#012Feb 10 15:16:20 mta03 postfix/qmgr[7419]: ABCDEF123: from=<>, size=24431, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

func BenchmarkSplitMessageExtra(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        msg := testMessage
        splitMessageExtra(&msg)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: extra
BenchmarkSplitMessageExtra-4    50000000            32.2 ns/op
PASS
ok      extra   1.647s
```

For comparison, here are the results from your code and benchmark. Your code and benchmark are slower than mine: 968 ns/op and 50.184s versus 32.2 ns/op and 1.647s respectively.

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

// Splits the main line from extra information
func splitMessageExtra(line *string) string {
    var prev rune
    for i, char := range *line {
        if prev == 0 && char == '#' {
            prev = char
            continue
        }
        if prev == '#' && char == '0' {
            prev = char
            continue
        }
        if prev == '0' && char == '1' {
            prev = char
            continue
        }
        if prev == '1' && char == '2' {
            extra := (*line)[i+1:]
            *line = (*line)[0 : i-3]

            return extra
        }
        prev = 0
    }
    return ""
}

var testMessage = `Feb 10 15:16:20 foo_stats[-] (warning): [foo_stats.postfix, line 166, thread "processor_mta03"]: Skipped line because there is no context:#012Feb 10 15:16:20 mta03 postfix/qmgr[7419]: ABCDEF123: from=<>, size=24431, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

func BenchmarkSplitMessageExtra(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        b.StopTimer()
        msg := string([]byte(testMessage))
        b.StartTimer()
        splitMessageExtra(&msg)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: extra
BenchmarkSplitMessageExtra-4     2000000           968 ns/op    
PASS
ok      extra   50.184s
```

Some of your code is unnecessary; it uses CPU time and triggers allocations. For example, converting to utf-8 bytes to runes,`for i, char := range *line {}`, and converting `string` to `[]byte` to `string`, `string([]byte(testMessage))` . Some algorithms could be improved. For example, searching for a newline.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your benchmark, but you are running the function repeatedly on the same input. Doesn't that mean that the first call of the function splits the string, and every following call just quickly checks that there is no line break and returns an empty string? The reason I did `string([]byte(testMessage))` in the test file was to deep copy the string, which is necessary since the function modifies its input.

Comment: Ok I see. I had some misapprehensions about strings in `go`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. `StopTimer` and `StartTimer` should be much more expensive than `splitMessageExtra`. Both of them call `runtime.ReadMemStats`. See [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13613).

Comment: How would you suggest resolving it? The function is designed to modify the input, so it would be wrong to include allocating memory in the benchmark. There should be a way to pause the timer without massive massive overhead.

Comment: Try using a much more complicated and longer `testMessage`. Maybe that's what you'd prefer.

Comment: That won't make any difference, currently the function runs about 10 million times per second...

Comment: Or use two `for` blocks instead of one `for`. First block does all the allocation and store result in a slice. Second block just calls `splitMessageExtra(&the_slice[msg_index])`. No need to `StopTimer` or `StartTimer` inside loop.

Comment: Good timing on that last comment :) I just tried that a few minutes ago, and it reduced the run time to around 5 seconds. I was just about to comment that here.